# Cannot find module '/workspace/mySQL/node_modules/faker/index.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, faker

Hello I'm trying to build a project but I cant get the terminal to run to the app.js file as it reports an error and I dont know how to fix it. Just to mention that I've downloaded faker package using (npm install faker), also I've created an app.js file and  npm init -y  to create a package.json for the warnings. But whenever I try to type ( node app.js) I get the following error:
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:329
throw err;
^

Error:
Cannot find module '/workspace/mySQL/node_modules/faker/index.js'. Please verify that
the package.json has a valid "main" entry

```
at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:321:19)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:534:18)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/mySQL/app.js:1:13)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) {

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
path: '/workspace/mySQL/node_modules/faker/package.json',
requestPath: 'faker'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXtLf.png)

Answer (score 0):

as I saw you have added files in the node-modules directory. Remove files from that directory into the main directory.

It will be like this

- Mysql

  - node-modules
  - app.js
  - package.json
  - file.sql